# How to get selected td value

Tags: php, jquery

I have a table with the image and image code data, show on code below:

```
<table id="tblForklift" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr id="image_info">
      <td id="1W 1111">
        <img src="../Client/images/forklift/corpus-christi-forklifts1.jpg" width="210px"     height="210px"/>
        <p style="text-align: center;">1W 1111</p>
      </td>
      <td id="2W 2222"></td>
      <td id="3W 3333"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr id="image_info"></tr>
   <tr id="image_info"></tr>
   <tr id="image_info"></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I tried using this code to get the html of selected td of the table. But it show "undefined".

```
$('#tblForklift').on('click', function(e) {
    var forkliftCode = $('this').closest('tr').find('td').html();
    alert(forkliftCode)
});
```

Comment: td isn't an interactive element, so "the selected td" doesn't necessarily mean anything; do you mean you want to detect if a particular td is clicked?

Comment: @IMSoP yeah..that what I mean...because the td and tr in this table is generate from another php file called B.php  . I just load the B.php tr and td and display in the table ID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `#tblForklift` will match your table. You need to target `td` elements inside this table instead. Also if your elements has been added dynamically to the DOM, you can use **[event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)**:

```
$(document).on('click', '#tblForklift tr td', function(e) {
    var forkliftCode = $(this).html();
    alert(forkliftCode)
});
```

or better if your table is not added dynamically:

```
$('#tblForklift').on('click', 'tr td', function(e) {
    var forkliftCode = $(this).html();
    alert(forkliftCode)
});
```

Also some of your `td` are missing closing `</td>`

Comment: yeap..i tried using this code..but it did not show any action once i clicked. Mention about this where my tr and td is generate from another B.php file. In this file I just load the B.php file and display the tr and td in the table ID.

Comment: @Felix ,Hello sir , Are you brother of Felix Kling   http://stackoverflow.com/users/218196/felix-kling  ,Or is that Your account? You both are genius :)

Comment: @Felix  Thanks BRO~..your solution help me alot..sorry for the late reply..hope can keep in touch with you soon..

Answer (score 0):

Add event to the td. so in each td click you can get html.

```
 $('#tblForklift td').on('click',function(e) {
       alert($( this ).html());
    });
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qsDn5/98/)

Answer (score 0):

`id` must be unique use `class` like,

**HTML**

```
<table id="tblForklift" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="image_info">
      <td class="1W 1111 forklift">
        <img src="../Client/images/forklift/corpus-christi-forklifts1.jpg" width="210px"     height="210px"/>
        <p style="text-align: center;">1W 1111</p>
      </td>
      <td class="2W 2222"></td>
      <td class="3W 3333"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="image_info"></tr>
   <tr class="image_info"></tr>
   <tr class="image_info"></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
$('.forklift').on('click', function(e) { // using class for multiple tds
    var forkliftCode = $(this).find('p').text();
    alert(forkliftCode);
});
```

Also, never give a space in a `id`, space has a different meaning in `jquery selectors`

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/86znJ/)

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
      <td class="2W 2222">cvbcxbcvb</td>
      <td class="3W 3333">bcvbcvbnvnv</td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="image_info"></tr>
   <tr class="image_info"></tr>
   <tr class="image_info"></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#tblForklift td').click(function() {
    alert($(this).html());
});
```